# Медленный JOIN таблиц в clickhouse

Tags: база-данных

У меня есть две таблицы

event

- id
- os

params

- id
- sx
- sy

Связь между ними 1-1. Если выполнить запрос с join

```
select count(*)
from
(select id from event where os like 'Android%')
inner join
(select id from params where sx >= 1024)
using id
```

То он работает очень медленно.

Если же все данные находятся в одной таблице и я делаю такой запрос

```
select count(*) from event where sx >= 1024 and os like 'Android%'
```

То он выполняется очень быстро.

Подскажите,как правильно, может быть, пользоваться join в ClickHouse, потому что держать все в одной таблице не удобно.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вот:

```
select count(*) from event e 
inner join params p on p.id = e.id
where e.os like 'Android%' and p.sx >= 1024
```

Далее смотреть индексы(`e.os` и `p.sx`).

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется быстро, то лучше таки держать данные в минимально возможном наборе таблиц и не делать join.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переписать запрос так:

```
select count(*)
from event 
where os like 'Android%' 
AND id IN (select id from params where sx >= 1024)
```

Comment: Использовал вложенный запрос, но скорость, к сожалению, все равно оставляет желать лучшего, если без вложенного запроса выполняется за 16 секунд, то с вложенным 78 секунд